# remove a character from a double

Tags: java, android, string, double

need to erase the last number of the operation.
newNumber is a Double and it is a widget of type button.
here is an example of what I need to do: 238.213 - buttonD = 238.21 (without the number "3" at the least). So every time the button is pressed one character goes off as in a keyboard.

```
Button buttonD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonD);

    buttonD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String nn = "";
            newNumber - nn; //newNumber is a Double

            //need to erase the last number of the operation
            //1234 - buttonD = 123
            //12133242.9231 - buttonD = 12133242.923

        }
    });
```

Comment: Make it a `BigDecimal` or a `String`, `double` doesn't have arbitrary precision.

Comment: Make it String and cut the last character off

Comment: Define your number format as well. And bigDecimal is away to go especially when dealing with decimals

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the double into string and delete last character. Then convert it back to double;

```
Button buttonD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonD);

buttonD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
            deleteOneChar(42.1037)
        }
    }
});

private Double deleteOneChar(double number) {
    String aoeu = String.valueOf(number);
    aoeu = aoeu.substring(0, aoeu.length() - 1);
    if (aoeu.chatAt(aoeu.length()-1).equals(",") || aoeu.chatAt(aoeu.length()-1).equals(".")) {
        aoeu = aoeu.substring(0, aoeu.length() - 1);
    }
    return Double.parseDouble(aoeu);
}
```

Comment: what you need to do is just put call `deleteOneChat(yournumberhere)`. You don't need to matter the variable inside method